# Is there a way to make sculpting amount not falloff when holding down the mouse?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, sculpt-mode

I'm new to blender sculpting, and I was wondering if there was a way to make the sculpting amount consistent when holding down the mouse. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information on this.

To elaborate; when holding down the mouse and continuing to make a stroke with the Draw brush, you will raise the geometry at first, but this will gradually falloff until you no longer impact it at all. Is there a way to continue raising the geometry consistently while going over the same area without lifting the mouse and starting a new stroke?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I had missed this when looking through that menu, it's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check *Accumulate* under the Brush Menu in the top of the 3D view interface while in sculpt mode.

[image]

Or in the Tool settings in the properties editor :

[image]

It's the same setting, just accessed from two different places in the interface.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! There are a lot of options to look through, but I'm still not sure how I missed it.